# Finding the force on a charge

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

I am trying to do the following problem;

A uniform surface charge lies in the region $z=0$ for $x^2+y^2 \gt a^2$ and $z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ for $x^2+y^2 \le a^2$, Find the force on a unit charge that is located at $(0,0,b)$

I am a bit confused because of the changing of the regions.

What I know;

For a point P,

$$dF=\frac{C(1)\sigma dS}{||PB||^{2}} u_{pb}$$

Where C is a constant, sigma the uniform charge, and u the unit vector.

ie

=
$$dF=\frac{C(1)\sigma dS PB}{||PB||^{3}}$$

Where $PB=-a\sin(\psi)\cos(\theta)i-a\sin(\psi)\sin(\theta)j+(b-a)\cos(\psi)k$

But I am just really confused on how to approach this specfic problem. I am looking for a solution/help. Thanks

Comment: You can find the net force as the sum of two forces: one is due to the charged plate $x^2 + y^2 > a^2$ and the second one due to the charged ellipsoid surface.

Comment: @Pavel  Thanks but I cant figure out how to actually set it up , I understand I could sum, but how to evaluate for each?

Comment: What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I am not sure. for the first part, it seems z is a sphere and then a cylinder but I am really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, lets assume that the point charge $Q$ and the surface charge density $\sigma$ are of the same sign, so that the charge is repelled by each point on the surface. We will represent the net force acting on the charge as $F_{net} = F_0 + F_{sph}$, where $F_0$ is the force created by the ring at $z=0$ with the inner radius $a$ and the outer radius $\rightarrow \infty$, and $F_{sph}$ is the force acting on the point charge due to the presence of hemispherical surface.

First, let us calculate $F_0$. Obviously, this force will be along the positive direction of the $z-$axis. Elementary force reads

$dF_0(r, \phi) = k\frac{\sigma rd\phi dr}{(r^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}b$,

where $k$ is the electrostatic constant, $r$ and $\phi$ are polar coordinates associated with the ring, and extra factor $b/\sqrt{r^2+b^2}$ is due to projection of this elementary force on the $z-$axis. Then, $F_0$ becomes

$F_0 = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_a^\infty dr k\frac{\sigma r}{(r^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}b = \frac{2\pi k\sigma b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Now we proceed with $F_{sph}$. Elementary force $dF_{sph}$ reads

$dF_{sph}(\phi,\theta) = k\frac{\sigma a^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi}{(a^2+b^2 - 2ab\cos\theta)^{3/2}}(b-a\cos\theta)$,

where $\theta$ is the angle between the $z-$axis and the radius-vector of the point on the hemisphere with respect to the origin. Then, $F_{sph}$ becomes

$F_{sph} = k\sigma a^2 \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta \frac{(b-a\cos\theta) \sin\theta }{(a^2+b^2 - 2ab\cos\theta)^{3/2}} = \frac{2\pi k \sigma a^2}{b^2}\bigg(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}\bigg)$.

Thus, the net force acting on the unit charge is

$F_{net} = \frac{2\pi k\sigma }{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\bigg(b + \frac{a^2}{b^2}\bigg(a + \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\bigg)\bigg)$.

In this solution I have omitted some minimal steps, but they should be easily recovered from the highlights above.

Hope this helps.